# Create recovery Samsung area

Tags: samsung-laptop

I would like to know how I can create the Samsung recovery partition that I accidentally deleted during a Windows installation, and consequently the F4 key does not work.  I have a PC from the year 2021.  a thousand thanks

Comment: What's a "Samsung recovery partition"? Is it a factory recovery partition in a Samsung laptop? If so I'm afraid it can't be recovered unless you obtain the original drive image from the manufacturer, know how to apply and understand that it will undo everything you did with the new Windows installation.

Comment: first of all thanks for the answer, yes it is the recovery partition of the samsung.  I saw that you can restore using the "adminTool" program or something like that, and also how do I get the original drive image from the manufacturer?  (they did not provide me with neither CD / DVD to restore).  a thousand thanks.  i downloaded samsung recovery tool 5 and 6 but it doesn't work.  https://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/376650-samsung-recovery-partition-missing-boot-f4-not-working.html

Comment: The recovery software *depends* on the partition you deleted.

Comment: i learned that with a program called admin tool, it can be recovered.  but I would like to download for my version in order for it to work, as adminTool 4/5 doesn't work.  a thousand thanks. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=4Nt--vBhRZI

Comment: somebody help me?

Comment: You probably need to watch the follow up video and understand that the tool does NOT contain recovery data, that it needs to get that data from somewhere. Typically it would be from the recovery partition that you deleted but can also be from the recovery DVD. You may or may not find it online (ISO file) at this point in time. This is your homework, nothing else to say here, there is no other answer that can be given.